# Remote Desktop IP missing in Event Log

Tags: windows-server-2003, remote-desktop, windows-event-log

I was checking my remote desktop event logs and an entry is confusing for me.

The event was a normal log on event with a username, but at details have a dash (`-`) for the source IP instead of a source IP address there.

The other events there have the correct source IP, so why does this entry not have an IP address for the source?

[image: Event log screenshot]

Here is the event log description
English: http://pastebin.com/CtHC6xKD
The text in the other window is the same except the IP.

Comment: Might be useful if you post a screenshot of the event.  Not anything to go on otherwise, TBH.

Comment: here is the schreenshot:
http://img138.imageshack.us/img138/5029/servereventlog.png

Comment: Better, but can you post the information that's scrolled off the window in those two event log windows?

Comment: It would be helpful to see the Logon Type for both of these events, which is nearer the top of the Event details window.

Comment: The caller PID is different on the event with the "-". That's a clue, I think. I suspect the "-" logon isn't an interactive logon coming in thru Winlogon.

Comment: Ok this doesen't works here in comments, here are the differences:  
http://pastebin.com/sz2MqpJg

Answer (score 0):

This is because client authenticating via network logon.
You need to change it to remote desktop connection

You can use this links for changing security settings https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc770833.aspx

If you have time check this one also
[Windows Events for Remote Desktop logon failure](https://serverfault.com/questions/711007/windows-events-for-remote-desktop-logon-failure)