# Windows Events for Remote Desktop logon failure

Tags: windows-server-2008, logging, remote-desktop, windows-event-log, remote-desktop-services

According to [ref](http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles-tutorials/misc_network_security/Logon-Types.html) the logon types 10 and 3 in windows events are represnting

Logon Type 10 = RemoteInteractive Logon
&

Logon Type 3  = Network Logon

But when i tried to connect a Windows machine via "Remote Desktop Connection" with a wrong username and password, remote machine generating  events with logon type 3 instead of 10. I checked with a lot machines. But still this is happening.

Could you explain why this happening?

log another details : [event all details](http://textuploader.com/artqw)

*Screenshots*

[image] 
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will get this logon type 3 when you are using NLA (Network Layer Authentication) as the authentication type since it will try and pre-authenticate you prior to giving you RDP access.

You can test this by changing the security layer to `RDP Security Layer`.  Instructions and detailed information on how to do so are found here: [Configure Server Authentication and Encryption Levels](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc770833.aspx) -- You should then find when typing an invalid username/password combination that it now logs it as logon type 10.